# Sliding Menu switching activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am trying to use a Sliding menu with the navigation drawer but using activities instead of fragments... So I have 3 activities to do that:

**Index.class**

```
mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));



    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);


    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
            R.string.app_name, 
            R.string.app_name 
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
public class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}


private void displayView(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent case0 = new Intent(this, Home.class); 
        startActivity(case0);
        break;
    case 1:
        Intent case1 = new Intent(this, FindPeople.class); 
        startActivity(case1);
        break;
    case 2:
        Intent case2 = new Intent(this, Photos.class); 
        startActivity(case2);
        break;
    case 3:
        Intent case3 = new Intent(this, Community.class); 
        startActivity(case3);
        break;
    case 4:
        Intent case4 = new Intent(this, Pages.class); 
        startActivity(case4);
        break;
    case 5:
        Intent case5 = new Intent(this, WhatsHot.class); 
        startActivity(case5);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

**NavDraweList.class**

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return navDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {       
    return navDrawerItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
        txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    }else{
        // hide the counter view
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

**NavDrawerItem.class**

```
private String title;
private int icon;
private String count = "0";
// boolean to set visiblity of the counter
private boolean isCounterVisible = false;

public NavDrawerItem(){}

public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon){
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon, boolean isCounterVisible, String count){
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
    this.count = count;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
}

public int getIcon(){
    return this.icon;
}

public String getCount(){
    return this.count;
}

public boolean getCounterVisibility(){
    return this.isCounterVisible;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public void setIcon(int icon){
    this.icon = icon;
}

public void setCount(String count){
    this.count = count;
}

public void setCounterVisibility(boolean isCounterVisible){
    this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
}
```

While I use Fragments all was good, but I modify the code to try to use activities and the app show me a Dark screen instead of the menu and the activities. So to resume, I am trying to show the same slinding menu in multiple activities because the fragments are a bit limited to some things...

I Hope you can help me :)

Comment: I hope you are aware of the use of the fragments. With fragments, you can have many layouts in a single activity side by side.

The reason behind using fragments in navigation drawer is that you can use new layouts for each fragments and alter them by clicking the menu item within a single activity.

Now if we use activities instead of the fragments that means you are launching an activity on each menu click. When launching an activity, the whole layout gets refreshed. So next activity that you use will not have the layout that the main activity was using.

Comment: Yes but, I want to start some connections and show rosters (XMPP) in my app. So I need to work with activities. I only use the main activity to generate the first connection and draw the menu. I think that is posible to show the same menu in all activities only writing: Home Extends Activity Implements MainActivity, or something like that. Well before that I need to show the menu an fix it to his properly work.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/  take a look this Slide Menu sample using fragments.